# Input type="password" com o olho de mostrar senha

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, razor

Preciso colocar um `<input type="password">` com aquele olho do revelar senha, porém tem que funcionar da seguinte maneira:

Usuário clica no olho e ao soltar esconde os caracteres novamente.

Segue uma foto de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que já testaste?

Comment: O que muitas páginas web utilizam é um `checkbox` `mostrar a senha`. Veja esse artigo interessante sobre isso http://tableless.com.br/precisamos-confirmar-senha/

Comment: Você já possui excelentes respostas, então deixarei [apenas esta forma](http://wsnippets.com/demo/bootstrap-show-hide-password/) utilizando bootstrap para tentar lhe mostrar "outra" forma (é a mesma que já foram apresentadas, mas de uma forma "diferente").

Comment: Em todas soluções abaixo existe um problema que no Edge aparece o que o navegador coloca automaticamente, e o feito manualmente.

Comment: @David não entendi, pode explicar com mais clareza ?

Comment: posso sim @devgaspa, abri essa pergunta no browser: Microsoft Edge, e o próprio browser coloca o "olho" em campos password, dessa forma ficando duplicado o ícone.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Usando jquery, faça o seguinte:

```
$( "#olho" ).mousedown(function() {
  $("#senha").attr("type", "text");
});

$( "#olho" ).mouseup(function() {
  $("#senha").attr("type", "password");
});
```

**Exemplo Completo:**

```js
var senha = $('#senha');
var olho= $("#olho");

olho.mousedown(function() {
  senha.attr("type", "text");
});

olho.mouseup(function() {
  senha.attr("type", "password");
});
// para evitar o problema de arrastar a imagem e a senha continuar exposta, 
//citada pelo nosso amigo nos comentários
$( "#olho" ).mouseout(function() { 
  $("#senha").attr("type", "password");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" value="123456789" id="senha">
<img id="olho" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABDUlEQVQ4jd2SvW3DMBBGbwQVKlyo4BGC4FKFS4+TATKCNxAggkeoSpHSRQbwAB7AA7hQoUKFLH6E2qQQHfgHdpo0yQHX8T3exyPR/ytlQ8kOhgV7FvSx9+xglA3lM3DBgh0LPn/onbJhcQ0bv2SHlgVgQa/suFHVkCg7bm5gzB2OyvjlDFdDcoa19etZMN8Qp7oUDPEM2KFV1ZAQO2zPMBERO7Ra4JQNpRa4K4FDS0R0IdneCbQLb4/zh/c7QdH4NL40tPXrovFpjHQr6PJ6yr5hQV80PiUiIm1OKxZ0LICS8TWvpyyOf2DBQQtcXk8Zi3+JcKfNafVsjZ0WfGgJlZZQxZjdwzX+ykf6u/UF0Fwo5Apfcq8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
/>
```

Comment: Desculpe amigo, mas no olho eu coloco o que?

Comment: Coloca isso - `id="olho"`

Comment: Em seu html, encontre aonde está aquele "olho" e acrescente o atributo "id" nele colocando como o @TaoPaiPai falou. :)

Comment: +1 Solução top.

Comment: Perfeita resposta, muito útil! ;) +1

Comment: @Vaati, ficou excelente, eu fiz um pouquinho diferente, vou colocar como eu fiz, ficou top! Ao invés de usar IMG eu usei um Icon... Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Se arrastar o olho e soltar o clique fora, o password fica exposto.

Comment: Código para resolução adicionado.

Answer (score 23):

Usando apenas JavaScript, podes adicionar a um elemento, neste caso é a tag `img`, dois eventos ([mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) e [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup)), estes iram alterar a propriedade `type` do `input`, alternando entre `text` e `password`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('olho').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  document.getElementById('pass').type = 'text';
});

document.getElementById('olho').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  document.getElementById('pass').type = 'password';
});

// Para que o password não fique exposto apos mover a imagem.
document.getElementById('olho').addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  document.getElementById('pass').type = 'password';
});
```

```css
#pass {
  width: 150px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.olho {
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icons-pack/100/ui-icon-pack-14-512.png" id="olho" class="olho">
<input type="password" id="pass">
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigado.

Comment: Excelente, me ajudou muito também! Obrigado @devgaspa

Comment: Se arrastar o olho e soltar o clique fora, o password fica exposto.

Comment: @bfavaretto alterei o código, não achei outra opção de imediato a não ser a implementada, se souber de alguma poderia compartilhar ? Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ser também no `dragend`.

Comment: @bfavaretto pelo que notei, o que acontece é o seguinte: quando você move o mouse com o botão pressionado (`mousedown`) ao soltar ele não reconhece que o `mouseup` é daquele elemento ?

Comment: @devgaspa é isso mesmo, o mouseup ocorre fora. O que significa que também dá pra resolver por delegação :)

Comment: @bfavaretto vou abrir uma pergunta, gostaria de ver o exemplo com delegação.

Comment: O Sergio colocou um exemplo com delegação na resposta dele agora.

Comment: @bfavaretto não encontro a resposta, pode me informar o link ?

Comment: Ué logo aqui embaixo :D

Answer (score 14):

Algumas das outras respostas mostram como mostrar /esconder a password quando se clicar no input, independentemente de onde se clique.

Para o clique ser num sítio específico, olho ou texto é preciso usar um outro elemento, uma imagem por exemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#input input');
var img = document.querySelector('#input img');
img.addEventListener('click', function () {
  input.type = input.type == 'text' ? 'password' : 'text';
});
```

```css
#input > * {
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
}

#input img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <input type="password" value="password" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Sb2.png" alt="">
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cj3kmxL4/

---

### Edit:

Para só mostrar o texto no `mousedown` e esconder de novo pode usar-se assim: http://jsfiddle.net/cj3kmxL4/1/, que no fundo usa os eventos `mouse(up|down)` e escuta o evento `mouseup` na `window`, para o caso de o `mouseup` ser fora do elemento.

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input input');
var img = document.querySelector('#input img');
var visivel = false;
img.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  visivel = true;
  input.type = 'text';
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  if (visivel) visivel = !visivel;
  input.type = 'password';
});
```

Comment: Quem deu o `-1` pode comentar se há algo de errado na minha resposta...

Comment: Achei interessante o modo como usou o operador ternário.

Comment: Sergio, ótimo o método usado em seu código para tratar o mouseup fora do elemento.

Answer (score 7):

Fiz um exemplo utilizando o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) para criar o olho e o script usado é basicamente o mesmo utilizado nas demais respostas.

```js
var $spnMostrarSenha = $('#spnMostrarSenha');
var $txtSenha = $('#txtSenha');

$spnMostrarSenha
  .on('mousedown mouseup', function() {
    var inputType = $txtSenha.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    $txtSenha.attr('type', inputType);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    $txtSenha.attr('type', 'password');
  });
```

```css
.form-group .glyphicon-eye-open {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.form-group .glyphicon-eye-open:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtSenha" value="password">
  <span id="spnMostrarSenha" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Diferente dos outros esse código no `IE 11` não aparece dois olhos. +1

Answer (score 2):

Galera olhem a solução que fiz, ficou exatamente do jeito que eu queria...

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 submit-line">
                <label>Senha:<span class="stf-color-asterisco">*</span></label>
                <div class="submit-line">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="uePassowrd" />
                    <button class="submit-eye" type="submit">
                        <i id="ueEyePass" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

javascript:

```
            $("#ueEyePass").mousedown(function () {
                $("#uePassowrd").attr("type", "text");
            });

            $("#ueEyePass").mouseup(function () {
                $("#uePassowrd").attr("type", "password");
            });
```

css:

```
.submit-eye {
              position:absolute;
              top:5px; right:0;
              z-index:10;
              border:none;
              background:transparent;
              outline:none;
            }

            .submit-line {
              position: relative;
              /*width: 600px;*/
            }

            .submit-line input {
              width: 100%;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript puro**

Mostra a senha ao clicar e enquanto o mouse estiver sobre o olho fica mostrando sem necessidade de ficar com mouse pressionado (acho cansativo) e basta retirar o mouse de cima do olho para esconder a senha.

```js
function mouseoverPass(obj) {
  var obj = document.getElementById('myPassword');
  obj.type = "text";
}
function mouseoutPass(obj) {
  var obj = document.getElementById('myPassword');
  obj.type = "password";
}
```

```css
#myPassword {
  width: 150px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.olho {
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
Mostra a senha ao clicar e enquanto o mouse estiver sobre o olho fica mostrando sem necessidade de ficar com mouse pressionado (acho cansativo) e basta retirar o mouse de cima do olho para esconder a senha.
<br>

<input type="password" name="password" id="myPassword" size="30" />
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABDUlEQVQ4jd2SvW3DMBBGbwQVKlyo4BGC4FKFS4+TATKCNxAggkeoSpHSRQbwAB7AA7hQoUKFLH6E2qQQHfgHdpo0yQHX8T3exyPR/ytlQ8kOhgV7FvSx9+xglA3lM3DBgh0LPn/onbJhcQ0bv2SHlgVgQa/suFHVkCg7bm5gzB2OyvjlDFdDcoa19etZMN8Qp7oUDPEM2KFV1ZAQO2zPMBERO7Ra4JQNpRa4K4FDS0R0IdneCbQLb4/zh/c7QdH4NL40tPXrovFpjHQr6PJ6yr5hQV80PiUiIm1OKxZ0LICS8TWvpyyOf2DBQQtcXk8Zi3+JcKfNafVsjZ0WfGgJlZZQxZjdwzX+ykf6u/UF0Fwo5Apfcq8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" onclick="mouseoverPass();" onmouseout="mouseoutPass();"  id="olho" class="olho"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer desse jeito, se caso alguem se interesse.

```html
<center>

<script>                        
function show() {
  var senha = document.getElementById("senha");
  if (senha.type === "password") {
    senha.type = "text";
  } else {
    senha.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>

<input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Digite a Senha" required>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="show()">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</center>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
<style type="text/css">
  #exibe{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background: #000;
  }
</style>
```

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function($){
      var $senha = $("#senha");
      $("#exibe").on('mouseup mousedown', function(resposta1){
        if ($senha.attr('type') == 'password') {
            $senha.attr("type", "text");
            }else{
            $senha.attr('type', 'password');
            }
          });
      });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="password" id="senha" value="password" />
<div id="exibe"></div>
```