# Password visivel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, textbox, password

Estou a construir um login em asp.net e quero que ao clicar na checkbox para mostrar a password ela seja mostrada.

**Design página asp**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="Titulo" class="divtitulo">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_administracao" runat="server" Text="Login Administração"></asp:Label>
</div>
<br />
 <div id="Login" class="divlogin" runat="server">
      <div id="wrapper">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_utilizador" runat="server" Text="Nome Utilizador:"></asp:Label>
          <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_utilizador" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>

<br />

<asp:Label ID="lbl_password" runat="server" Text="Palavra-Passe:"></asp:Label>
          <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" TextMode="Password" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>

<br />

<asp:CheckBox ID="chbox_mostrarpassword" runat="server" Text="Mostrar Palavra-Passe" />

<br />

<asp:Button ID="bt_login" runat="server" Text="Iniciar Sessão" />
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Input type="password" com o olho de mostrar senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102024/input-type-password-com-o-olho-de-mostrar-senha)

Comment: Não a pergunta é diferente! Eu quero quando a checkbox estiver checked e nao so quando estiver a clicar

Comment: Eu entendi @José, mas essa pergunta faz o que você precisa, que é mudar o tipo do `input`, o restante é só fazer alguma pequena alteração no código, o objetivo é o mesmo, só não é uma resposta do tipo copiar e colar, mas entendendo é simples de fazer no seu código

Comment: isso nao funcionou. Será que é por ser uma asp.net com uma MasterPage?

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar no  evento onchange do checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chbox_mostrarpassword" runat="server"
 Text="Mostrar Palavra-Passe" 
 onchange="document.getElementById('lbl_password').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'" />
```

> Referencias

[**Add Option to Show password**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058185/add-the-option-show-password-to-asp-net-login-control?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: como posso fazer isso em Client Side para que não tenha de ir ao servidor para voltar atrás?

Comment: isso já está no  cliente site, é um função javascript

Comment: mude  o  runat=server  para runat=client